# Highlight all instances of a given word in a PDF.

Tags: pdf, search, highlighting

I want to highlight, preferably permanently, all instances of a search result in a PDF. For example, I want to highlight all examples of the word 'class' in a piece about Karl Marx to make finding the material I need to make notes on easier.

I suspect the reason I can't do this on either Foxit or Adobe Reader is that they both re-scan the document every time you highlight a search result, and this takes a long time.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: It had to be verified whether it does actually work in Acrobat Reader DC (or XI), but it is possible to parse the document page by page, and search for the according keyword, and create the highlight annotation, and save the document.

Answer (score 4):

Open the PDF using Firefox browser and click the "highlight all" button after you open the Find dialog.

[Find Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGSmx.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, the dialog shown in the linked image provided by Greg H is not the dialog that opens when searching a PDF document in Firefox, if the Adobe Reader plugin for Firefox is installed. The FF Adobe plugin does not offer "highlight all". In Chrome (for which I don't have the Adobe Reader plugin installed) the native PDF viewer does not offer the "highlight all" option.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have pressed Ctrl+F and searched the word, if you press Shift+Enter, it would higlight all the words matching your inquiry

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I discovered is to use the redaction tool. Change your redaction property from black to yellow, then use the "Text Overlay" function to re-enter that same word on the redaction mark

Comment: While this works (upvoted!) it's an ugly hack that causes Acrobat to consider the selected text as redacted and so this may be undesirable if the PDF is ever re-saved.

Answer (score 0):

Free version of [PDF-XChange Editor](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) (Windows, [Linux via Wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=15599)) highlights all entries for the keyword, and on top of that adds colored ticks on the scrollbar à la Chromium.
Also, navigation (scrolling/jumping back and forth across pages) is as fast and the program remains as responsive as simpler yet more lightweight alternatives such as [MuPDF](https://mupdf.com/) or [Sumatra PDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) even when working with huge PDF files (hundreds of megabytes, thousands pages with illustrations).

All instances of a given word can be displayed by using *Find…* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) tool for a quick preliminary lookup:

[image]

Using *Search…* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) tool for additional gathering of a complete list for all encounters.
Here, it only took one second to find 1139 entries in a 1300-page document, which I think is quite fast. Note, however, that this is "clean" document properly compiled from LaTeX source, and on a file that's been scanned and OCRed it could take longer:

[image]

Finally, by choosing *Options… → Annotate search results → Highlight Search Results* one can add permanent marks to the document and also save the changes to the PDF file:

[image]

**Disclaimer**: I am only a user, not a developer of PDF-XChange Editor and I'm not affiliated with Tracker software company.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing but using pattern matching to find certain types of strings? For example, say I want to highlight all places in a PDF that follow `(...)`. Meaning, starts with a (, has digits inbetween and ends with ).

Answer (score 0):

Open the PDF in MS Word (presumably Google Docs as well). Then select replace -> enter your search word or phrase and repeat that in the replace word box -> then near bottom select the replace Format drop down and select highlight -> then select replace all and it will highlight all instances. When done -> Save as PDF.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).